# Cannot execute sqlite command on remote host via Ansible - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sqlite3'"

Tags: sqlite, ansible

I am trying to run a simple query on many servers. I know 100% that the file and directory in question exist.

I can do simple commands, such as `ls`, `pwd`, `whoami`, etc, and I can run the `sqlite` command on the remote host itself.

The playbook task:

```
- name: Do a test SELECT statement
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  command: sqlite3 /usr/local/share/sqlite/dbfile.sqlite3 "SELECT * FROM db WHERE hostname="{{ db_server_prompt }}""
  register: query_result

- debug: var=query_result.stdout_lines
```

The error I'm receiving is  `"msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sqlite3'",`.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Why is it telling me there's "`No such file or directory`" when using the sqlite3 command? I've tried the absolute path to the executable (`/usr/bin/sqlite3`), but I get the same error.

I tried to use `chdir` as an argument per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/769898/running-python-script-on-anisble), but I get `Unable to change directory before execution`. None of these things are working. I would really like to use Ansible, since there are 20+ servers where this is needed.

**Update** I can run it as an adhoc command:

`ansible sqlite_servers_test -m command -a "sqlite3 /usr/local/share/sqlite/dbfile.sqlite3 "SELECT * FROM db_pool WHERE hostname=myhostname" "`

What is the difference in trying to run it via a playbook?

Comment: The difference is `become: true` which probably means that `sqlite3` is in the `PATH` for the "normal" user you use when running the ad-hoc command but not for root.

Comment: When I `echo $PATH` for both root and the ansible user, I see `/usr/bin`, unless I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: How to you echo it? With an ad-hoc command? Chances are your are echoing the local path of your local user in that case. The good tests IMO are 1) `command: which sqlite3` 2) provide the full path and see if it works 3) set `PATH` in an `environment` stanza in your task and see if it works. Anyway, your system is telling your it cannot find the command it the current PATH, and sorry but, computer usually wins against human in those cases ;)

Comment: I ran `echo $PATH` on the remote host, and did the same with an adhoc on my local machine. Got the same results both ways. `which sqlite3` works as adhoc, but not in playbook.

How would I set `PATH` in an environment stanza? I'm trying to find that in the Ansible docs, but I must be searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html . Did you run the ad-hoc command with `-b` to escalate privileges as well ?

Comment: I added: 

`environment: 
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'`

to the task, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with window and do not want to install sqlite3 permanently (in my case, I just want to update some table fields of `*.db` sqlite file stored in window, do not want to install sqlite3 at the window), I downloaded `sqlite3.exe` and copy to window to execute my ansible. After that sqlite3 is deleted from window.

[Download link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

[Sample code](https://github.com/khinthidasan/ansible-related/blob/main/sqlite3_for_window_by_ansible).